# Why do we need self referential object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

why do we need self referential object in javascript.
example

```
let a = {};
a.self = a;
```

now a property self is referring to itself and become circular object.

in nodejs when we use routing library like hapi.
the request object which we receive is circular

Comment: Ask this code author why they did it. It's not that we "need it" for some general reason.

Comment: "routing library like hapi. the request object which we receive is circular" --- ask the `hapi` developers why they do it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*EDIT: I understood this question to ask "why are circular references allowed in JavaScript".*

In general, I'd say an object having itself as a value of its property (`a.self = a`) is not very useful. If you have the reference to the object to take its property, you already have the reference to the object.

However, if the self-reference is deeper, then it makes a lot of sense. For example, trees that allow navigation up:

```
let tree = { children: [], parent: null };
tree.children.push({ children: [], parent: tree });
```

Here, `tree.children[0].parent === tree`. You have a circular object, but it serves a clear purpose: you can traverse the tree both downwards (via `children`) and upwards (via `parent`).

Comment: I've also seen people set the property to itself instead of `null` to avoid type errors

Answer (score 3):

We don't.

> Ask this code author why they did it. – zerkms